# Couldn't install orm-pack in Symfony 5.1

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, composer-php

I'm trying to install Doctrine ORM in my Symfony 5.1 project and I get the following errors:

```
composer require symfony/orm-pack
Using version ^1.1 for symfony/orm-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.1.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle v2.0.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~3.4|~4.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for symfony/orm-pack ^1.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/orm-pack[v1.1.0].
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.1
    - symfony/orm-pack v1.1.0 requires doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle ^2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, v2.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.1.0, 3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.1.1, 3.0.1].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[2.1.2, 3.0.1].
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle (locked at 3.0.1) -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle[3.0.1].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

What versions do I need to be able to use Doctrine in Symfony 5.1?
I've tried installing

```
composer req doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle:2.0
composer require symfony/orm-pack:1.1
```

But both failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's already some kind of issue about this, see https://github.com/symfony/orm-pack/issues/18 or https://github.com/symfony/orm-pack/issues/29 - the problem: since the last release, the ORM pack requires Doctrine v2. And according to the list of packages you've provided, you required `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle 3.0.1` before that.

There are two possible solutions: either downgrade `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` and other Doctrine related packages to v2 until the error message vanishes, or skip the ORM pack and require the packages written in that pack. If you already installed the migrations bundle, there is no benefit in installing `symfony/orm-pack` additionally

Comment: Thank you so much, I went with the second option and everything works OK now.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone getting the "**Could not parse version constraint orm-pack**" error when attempting to require `orm-pack`, [here's the key](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/820#issuecomment-942016309), then run:

`composer require orm`

https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/820#issuecomment-942016309